# Wrongs in close of trades in MQL4

Tags: datetime, conditional-operator, mql4, metatrader4, fclose

I created this code to Open trade if conditions true and close them if conditions true
But he only Open trade and not close them.

This is my code

```
extern double lotSize = 0.02;

extern double stopLoss = 50;

extern double takeProfit = 100;

extern double targetProfit = 1;

datetime tradeOpenTime = 0;

int slippage = 3;

// دالة لفتح صفقة شراء

void OnTick() {

//void OpenBuyOrder() {

if (true) {

if (TimeCurrent() > tradeOpenTime + PeriodSeconds()) {

if (TimeMinute(TimeCurrent()) == 0) {

if ((Close[1] < Open[1]) && (Close[2] < Open[2]) && (Close[2] < Open[2])) {

OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotSize, MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_ASK), slippage, 0, 0, "", 0, clrNONE);

tradeOpenTime = TimeCurrent();

}

}

}

}

//}

// دالة لشروط فتح صفقة بيع

//void OpenSellOrder() {

if (true) {

if (TimeCurrent() > tradeOpenTime + PeriodSeconds()) {

if (TimeMinute(TimeCurrent()) == 0) {

if ((Close[1] > Open[1]) && (Close[2] > Open[2]) && (Close[2] > Open[2])) {

OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, lotSize, MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_BID), slippage, 0, 0, "", 0, clrNONE);

tradeOpenTime = TimeCurrent();

}

}

}

}

//}

// دالة لإغلاق صفقات شراء وبيع بشروط معينة

//void CloseOrdersBasedOnConditions() {

if (OrdersTotal() == 1) {

//if (true) {

if (TimeCurrent() > tradeOpenTime + PeriodSeconds()) {

if (TimeMinute(TimeCurrent()) == 0) {

if ((Close[1] > Open[1]) && (OrderType() == OP_BUY)) {

OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID), 2, clrNONE);

} else if ((Close[1] < Open[1]) && (OrderType() == OP_SELL)) {

OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK), 2, clrNONE);

}

}

}

}

//}

// دالة لإغلاق جميع الصفقات إذا كان الربح الإجمالي يساوي القيمة المحددة

//void CloseAllOrdersIfProfitReached() {

else if (OrdersTotal() > 1) {

//if (true) {

double totalProfit = 0;

for (int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) {

totalProfit += OrderProfit();

}

}

if (totalProfit >= targetProfit) {

for (int x = OrdersTotal() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {

if (OrderSelect(x, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) {

OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID), 2, clrNONE);

}

}

}

}

//}

}
```

I have written this code to open trades when the conditions are met. If the conditions for buying are met, it opens a buy trade, and if the conditions for selling are met, it opens a sell trade. Additionally, there are conditions for closing a trade when a specific condition is met. There's also a condition to close trades when the total profit reaches a certain dollar amount. However, my problem is that this code only opens trades and doesn't close them when the conditions are met.

Comment: @PaulB - when editing questions please do not change the code at all. You might introduce a breakage or a fix that you do not intend, which would invalidate the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CloseAllOrdersIfProfitReached` you're iterating open trades and close them at `MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID)` which is BUY related.

Better close them at `OrderClosePrice()` which is direction neutral.

Comment: Your comment may be correct if this was programmed in MQL5, however the question specifically relates to MQL4, therefore either `Ask` or `Bid` must be used to determine the correct close price based on the order type.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise this option is not available for MQL4. Your suggestions in the code appear to be the working solution for the problem we both noticed.

Answer (score 0):

The appears to be multiple errors in your code and approach. I'd suggest the following revisions:

```
extern double lotSize = 0.02;
extern double stopLoss = 50;
extern double takeProfit = 100;
extern double targetProfit = 1;
datetime timebar, tradeOpenTime=0;
int slippage = 30;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
//---
//---
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
//---
//---
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{

   //CloseAllOrdersIfProfitReached
   if(OrdersTotal()>1)
   {
      double totalProfit = 0;
      for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) totalProfit+=OrderProfit();
      if(totalProfit>=targetProfit)
      {
         for(int x=OrdersTotal()-1; x>=0; x--)
         {
            if(OrderSelect(x, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
            {
               if(OrderType()==OP_BUY) bool res=OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, slippage, clrNONE);
               else bool res=OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 50, clrNONE);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   if(timebar==Time[0]) return;

   //CloseOrdersBasedOnConditions
   for(int x=OrdersTotal()-1; x>=0; x--)
   {
      if(OrderSelect(x, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
      {
         if(Close[1]>Open[1] && OrderType()==OP_BUY) bool res=OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, 2, clrNONE);
         else if(Close[1]<Open[1] && OrderType()==OP_SELL) bool res=OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 2, clrNONE);
      }
   }

   //OpenBuyOrder
   if(Close[1]<Open[1] && Close[2]<Open[2])
   {
      bool res=OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotSize, Ask, slippage, 0, 0, "", 0, clrNONE);
      tradeOpenTime = TimeCurrent();
   }

   //OpenSellOrder
   if(Close[1]>Open[1] && Close[2]>Open[2])
   {
      bool res=OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, lotSize, Bid, slippage, 0, 0, "", 0, clrNONE);
      tradeOpenTime = TimeCurrent();
   }

timebar=Time[0];
return;
}
```